# Jersey 2.0 Injecting HttpServletRequest into ExceptionMapper

Tags: jersey-2.0

I use Jersey 2.3.1, and i have the below exception mapper.

```
@Provider    
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {  
  @Context
   private HttpServletRequest reqeust;
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
 ....
}
}
```

When the application starts it throws below exception stating CustomExceptionMapper is not in requestscope.

The same code was working fine with Jersey 1.8 but when i migrated to 2.3.1 it is not working.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.exception.CustomExceptionMapper errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:328)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:57)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:53)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:860)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:152)
    at com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory.<init>(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1092)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:261)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:336)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:560)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:792)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:801)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:874)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:866)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:485)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
MultiException stack 3 of 4
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.exception.CustomExceptionMapper
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:57)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:53)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:860)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:152)
    at com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory.<init>(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1092)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:261)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:336)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:560)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:792)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:801)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:874)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:866)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:485)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
MultiException stack 4 of 4
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:560)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:792)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:801)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:874)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:866)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:485)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Nov 21, 2013 11:07:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /jerseyNew threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java:226)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:154)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:590)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ReferencingFactory.provide(ReferencingFactory.java:101)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:96)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:69)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ContextInjectionResolver.resolve(ContextInjectionResolver.java:104)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:208)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:328)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:57)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:53)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:860)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:152)
    at com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory.<init>(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1092)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:261)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:336)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:560)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:792)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:801)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:874)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:866)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:485)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am bit struggling with this, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use newer version of Jersey (the latest release is [2.4.1](https://jersey.java.net/download.html)). This issue ([JERSEY-1960](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960)) has been fixed in [2.4](https://jersey.java.net/release-notes/2.4.html). If this doesn't work for you, you can use a workaround (after filing an issue to our JIRA):

```
@Inject
private java.inject.Provider<org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Ref<HttpServletRequest>> request;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michal, your workaround worked well, i will try to use the latest version and see how it goes

Comment: I tested it, in the latest version (2.4.1) it worked fine without workaround.

Comment: Updated Issue link: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/2627